# C# Socket connection doesn't work

Tags: c#, sockets, message, send

I'm Trying to create a code to send a TCP message to a server.

When I use AutoIT Script Language with this code:

```
Example()

Func Example()

Local $ConnectedSocket, $szData

Local $szIPADDRESS = "10.200.0.104"

Local $nPORT = 1040

; Start The TCP Services

TCPStartup()

; Initialize a variable to represent a connection

$ConnectedSocket = -1

;Attempt to connect to SERVER at its IP and PORT 1040


$ConnectedSocket = TCPConnect($szIPADDRESS, $nPORT)

; If there is an error... show it

If @error Then
MsgBox(4112, "Error", "TCPConnect failed with WSA error: " & @error)


Else


$szData="0x0021601FA10706052B0C00815ABE14281206072B0C00821D8148A007A0050303000800000DA20B0201013006020200D30500"

TCPSend($ConnectedSocket, $szData)

EndIf

EndFunc;==>Example
```

Works fine but I need to write the same code in C#. I try to do this:

```
private static byte[] MessageToByteArray(string message, Encoding encoding)
        {
            var byteCount = encoding.GetByteCount(message);
            if (byteCount > byte.MaxValue)
                throw new ArgumentException("Message size is greater than 255 bytes in the provided encoding");
            var byteArray = new byte[byteCount + 1];
            byteArray[0] = (byte)byteCount;
            encoding.GetBytes(message, 0, message.Length, byteArray, 1);
            return byteArray;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string message = "0x0021601FA10706052B0C00815ABE14281206072B0C00821D8148A007A0050303000800000DA20B0201013006020200D30500";
            var byteArray = MessageToByteArray(message, Encoding.ASCII);

            Socket m_socClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);

            System.Net.IPAddress ipAdd = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("10.200.0.104");
            System.Net.IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAdd, 1040);
            m_socClient.Connect(remoteEP);

            try
            {

                m_socClient.Send(byteArray);
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(se.Message.ToString());
            }



        }
```

But this code doesn't work. The server shows when he receives the command. With C# code, the server shows that have connected but the command doesn't execute.

Comment: Why does the c# code get a length prefix and the AutoIT Script doesn't?

Comment: Also does the server show when the command is received or when the command is executed? Presumably sending an invalid packet wouldn't execute the command

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have to prefix the length?

```
byteArray[0] = (byte)byteCount;
encoding.GetBytes(message, 0, message.Length, byteArray, 1);
```

Often you have a null-terminated string:

```
encoding.GetBytes(message, 0, message.Length, byteArray, 0);
byteArray[byteArray.Length - 1] = (byte)'\0';
```

Comment: Or possibly just the string if the packet is a fixed size

Comment: Yes. If it is a fixed size I'd use zero-padding at the end.